# sum of array elements(any order) equal to k not continuous elements

Tags: algorithm

I have 2 input

```
array: {3,6,9,0,2,1,3} // positive number and can repeat also
Sum = 9
Need to find a combination(order not mandatory) of array element which has total to Sum(here for example it's 9).
```

Output expected :

```
{3,6}
{9}
{6,3}
{3,2,1,3}
```

I am not able to solve it. So, please don't ask for my solution. Please help by solving in java.

Comment: This is the subset sum problem

Comment: This could answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818406/find-a-solution-to-subset-sum-using-dynamic-programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved by printing all the subsets with given sum.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
// A Java program to count all subsets with given sum. 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
public class SubSet_sum_problem 
{ 
    // dp[i][j] is going to store true if sum j is 
    // possible with array elements from 0 to i. 
    static boolean[][] dp; 

    static void display(ArrayList<Integer> v) 
    { 
    System.out.println(v); 
    } 

    // A recursive function to print all subsets with the 
    // help of dp[][]. Vector p[] stores current subset. 
    static void printSubsetsRec(int arr[], int i, int sum, 
                                        ArrayList<Integer> p) 
    { 
        // If we reached end and sum is non-zero. We print 
        // p[] only if arr[0] is equal to sun OR dp[0][sum] 
        // is true. 
        if (i == 0 && sum != 0 && dp[0][sum]) 
        { 
            p.add(arr[i]); 
            display(p); 
            p.clear(); 
            return; 
        } 

        // If sum becomes 0 
        if (i == 0 && sum == 0) 
        { 
            display(p); 
            p.clear(); 
            return; 
        } 

        // If given sum can be achieved after ignoring 
        // current element. 
        if (dp[i-1][sum]) 
        { 
            // Create a new vector to store path 
            ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>(); 
            b.addAll(p); 
            printSubsetsRec(arr, i-1, sum, b); 
        } 

        // If given sum can be achieved after considering 
        // current element. 
        if (sum >= arr[i] && dp[i-1][sum-arr[i]]) 
        { 
            p.add(arr[i]); 
            printSubsetsRec(arr, i-1, sum-arr[i], p); 
        } 
    } 

    // Prints all subsets of arr[0..n-1] with sum 0. 
    static void printAllSubsets(int arr[], int n, int sum) 
    { 
        if (n == 0 || sum < 0) 
        return; 

        // Sum 0 can always be achieved with 0 elements 
        dp = new boolean[n][sum + 1]; 
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) 
        { 
            dp[i][0] = true; 
        } 

        // Sum arr[0] can be achieved with single element 
        if (arr[0] <= sum) 
        dp[0][arr[0]] = true; 

        // Fill rest of the entries in dp[][] 
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) 
            for (int j = 0; j < sum + 1; ++j) 
                dp[i][j] = (arr[i] <= j) ? (dp[i-1][j] || 
                                        dp[i-1][j-arr[i]]) 
                                        : dp[i - 1][j]; 
        if (dp[n-1][sum] == false) 
        { 
            System.out.println("There are no subsets with" + 
                                                " sum "+ sum); 
            return; 
        } 

        // Now recursively traverse dp[][] to find all 
        // paths from dp[n-1][sum] 
        ArrayList<Integer> p = new ArrayList<>(); 
        printSubsetsRec(arr, n-1, sum, p); 
    } 

    //Driver Program to test above functions 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        int arr[] = {3, 6, 9, 0, 2, 1, 3}; 
        int n = arr.length; 
        int sum = 9; 
        printAllSubsets(arr, n, sum); 
    } 
}
```

**Output:**

```
[6, 3]
[9]
[0, 6, 3]
[0, 9]
[1, 2, 6]
[1, 2, 0, 6]
[3, 6]
[3, 0, 6]
[3, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 1, 2, 0, 3]
```